# What's wrong with this if/while loop?

Tags: java, loops

Could someone explain what is wrong with this code? It looks ok to me, but it keeps saying that there is an illegal start of the expression, and {} is expected even though it's there.

```
if (gamestate = 1) {
    while (life > 0) {
        if (atk > enemydef) {
            atk1 = atk - enemydef;
            enemylife = enemylife - atk1;
            System.in.println("Enemy health: " + enemylife);
            System.in.println("Your Health" + life);
        }
        if else(atk<enemydef) {
                        enemylife = enemylife;
        } else {
            enemylife = enemylife;
        }
    }
else {
    System.out.println("GAME OVER");
}
```

Comment: @Makoto: your edit put the brace for the while loop right before the else instead of on a separate line like it was before. You shouldn't make significant edits like that when the problem is clearly one of syntax.

Comment: @Geobits: yes, the brace is still missing, but it's even less obvious now due to the edit.

Comment: one thing you guys are really missing is the fact that it says System.in.println

Comment: IntelliJ gets a little zealous over formatting sometimes.  My bad.

Comment: @SalomonMatthewExume Is the question some sort of test, then? If you know what's wrong with it, fix it.

Comment: @Sal Then you should fix it in your question, since this is your question...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
if else (atk < enemydef)
```

to this:

```
else if (atk < enemydef)
```

It's `else if`, not `if else`. And also fix this:

```
if (gamestate = 1)
```

Change it to this:

```
if (gamestate == 1)
```

The correct comparison operator is `==`, if you write a single `=` then an assignment is performed, not an equality comparison.

Comment: oh thank you. its been so long since ive coded in java. ive forgottien so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(gamestate = 1)
```

should be

```
if (gamestate == 1)
```

For the sake of completeness, I will also point out that you have a problem with `if else`. The proper syntax is `else if`.

Comment: Yoda conditionals are unnecessary in Java and C# since you can't assign variables in an if-statement in such a fashion unless the variable is a boolean (in which case you'd probably be excluding the equality operator in the first place).

Comment: @siride Yes, you are correct; they are unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There's a handful of things wrong here.

- `if (gamestate = 1)` should be `if (gamestate == 1)`.  Single equals sign is assignment; double equals sign is boolean equivalence comparison.
- `if else` is not a valid expression.  You probably mean `else if`.
- You are missing a brace from in front of your `else` statement.  IntelliJ (which is what I use to format questions/answers here) didn't trust that it was its own statement, so it lumped it together with the other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It's `else if` not `if else`.  The line

```
if else(atk<enemydef)
```

should be

```
else if (atk<enemydef)
```

Also the line

```
if(gamestate = 1)
```

Needs to be

```
if (gamestate == 1)
```

The `=` operation is assigment while the `==` is the equality operator.  `gamestate = 1` will always set `gamestate` to `1`